# How can I boot my MacBook Pro from a DVD to update my SSD firmware

Tags: ssd, bootable-disk, firmware

I have a MacBook Pro 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 (mid-2011 model) running OS X 10.8.2.  I upgraded to an SSD which I bought from Crucial and works just great.  Crucial sent an email recommending I upgrade my firmware to get even better performance from my [SSD](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=684B05FFA5CA7304).

I downloaded the firmware to my desktop in the form of an ISO file from [the Crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/uk/support/ssd/index.aspx?source=web&cpe=m4firmware_uk), and the instructions told me to burn this to a disk and change my boot order in order to boot from this disk.  I burned the disk but subsequently have not been able to get a bios screen or to be able to boot from the DVD I created.  I have tried holding down the C key but nothing seems to happen.

What do I need to do to complete the installation of the firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide provided by Crucial [here](http://edge.crucial.com/firmware/m4/010G/CrucialFirmware_m42-5_010G.pdf) is quite PC-hardware centric, that's why they talk about BIOS, I guess. Forget BIOS in a Mac context.

You say you burned a DVD. I've downloaded the ISO file from the [update page](http://www.crucial.com/uk/support/ssd/index.aspx?source=web&cpe=m4firmware_uk), burned a CD and **I couldn't boot from it either** when pressing 'C' upon restart (as explained here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533]. The CD spun, but except for the noise nothing happened. (I own a Macbook Pro 2.2 GHZ Intel Core i7 (early 2011)).

I've checked the ISO file, it is a Linux boot CD that I suspect is not tuned for Mac hardware. I'd say contact Crucial customer support.

(The guide states:

> Firmware version 010G includes improvements which are specific for
>   Windows 8 and new UltraBook systems, although Windows 7 and other
>   operating systems and computer platforms may also see improvements.

so maybe you are not missing much...)

Comment: Thanks I'll let them know but I didn't realize how windoze specific the update is so I guess I will just leave it be.

Comment: Just to complete this topic here is the reply from Crucial:                                     Thank you for your email. A Firmware update should only be done if it addresses a certain issue and this new Firmware update isn't needed for the Macbook Pro.

Our Firmware tool is compatible with a MAC and it sounds like the ISO file hasn't downloaded as it should have.

If you want to go ahead with the update then I would recommend trying the download again or connecting the drive to a Windows based system and trying again.

If you have any further questions or need further help, just let us know.

Comment: Just wanted to share this: I inserted the firmware CD my Mac couldn't boot from into my wife's PC (Dell Inspiron / Windows 7) and it booted into the Crucial firmware tool without a hitch.

Answer (score 3):

You should know there is no such this as "BIOS" on a Mac (the equivalent system is called EFI, but you don't boot into it to change settings). To boot from a DVD or any other external medium, you'll have to hold down the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key while booting.
Then you'll get a list with all the bootable devices and there you can select the device you want to boot from.

Or you can go to System Preferences > Startup Disk to select your disk and then reboot. Then you'll also boot from the disk.

Comment: I didn't know any of that so thanks.  I unfortunately can't vote up the answer until my rep goes up but will then.  In this situation my disk does not show up in the startup disk window so I think as jaume pointed out this image is just not good for a MAC and I would have no confidence in it anyway at this point.