# MBP with Mountain Lion 10.8.3 loses connection to system SSD at random times and freezes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, performance

So, out of nowhere my 2009 MacBook (2,66 GHz Core 2 Duo, 8 GByte aftermarket ram) started freezing after 200+ days of uptime (sleep time included of course). I had installed a Crucial CT256M4SSD2 256Gbyte SSD a year and a half ago and were quite happy with system stability.

Now these logs appear quite often before freezing my machine completely:

```
disk0s2: no such device
disk0s2: media is not present
```

Here is a photograph of such a log (original, larger sized photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrcXx.jpg)):

[image]

The reason I had to do a photo is, of course, because disk0s2 is my harddrive and at the moment of logging it was apparently gone - so no persistent logs for me.

I tried a diagnose and repair with the Disk Utility, but it found nothing and the problem persisted. Uninstalled a couple of apps, but also to no avail. Any advice on how to proceed with diagnosing the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an external hard drive enclosure? You could insert the SSD in it and start up from it. See if the problem persists. If so, likely the SSD is at fault, if not the SATA cable connecting your SSD to the motherboard might be broken. Another indicator of the latter is a malfunctioning sleep light as the light is on the same cable ribbon as the SATA cable.

Comment: Bought a new SSD, now everything is fine. I guess SMART is not so smart after all. Didn't get a single clue from any health readings.

Comment: Dear god man, 200+ days of uptime?  I don't know if that's insane or awesome.  Why?!?

Comment: @Harv frankly because I can :) I enjoy opening the laptop and having the os up and running. So much better than the sleep functionality on Windows machines. I don't think the long uptime was a contributing factor on the SSD giving up on me though.

Answer (score 3):

A [firmware update](http://www.crucial.com/uk/support/firmware.aspx) for that SSD was released early this year: have you updated?  The release notes mention:

> Resolved a power-up timing issue that could result in a drive hang, resulting in an inability to communicate with the host computer. The hang condition would typically occur during power-up or resume from Sleep or Hibernate. Most often, a new power cycle will clear the condition and allow normal operations to continue.

(Personally I'm using a CT128M4SSD2 and have decided not to update unless I encounter issues.)

Comment: Why is this down voted? Did the firmware update not solve the problem? Please add a comment to your downvote as this gives the answerer the chance to improve the answer.

Comment: That is a good find. Although it seems to be impossible to upgrade the firmware on a mac and I don't have a windows machine handy right now. Also, it has nothing to do with sleep modes. It happens in full operation when the disk is accessed.

Comment: @keyboardsamurai Ah: I didn't realise that Crucial hadn't really provided a firmware update process for Macs :( (Relevant Ask Different questions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83713/copy-crucial-ssd-firmware-update-iso-to-bootable-usb) and [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68814/how-can-i-boot-my-macbook-pro-from-a-dvd-to-update-my-ssd-firmware).)  I think it would certainly be worth a try for your situation, though: note the word "typically" in the quote from the release notes.  Perhaps install Boot Camp to be able to run the Crucial update?  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably similar to a horrific bug in the original firmware of my Crucial SSD (I think a different model, but I don't work on that machine anymore). After a certain number of hours—so the long uptime is relevant, but in a *lifetime* way—the drive would shut down every hour, after exactly 60 minutes. I assume this was some testing code that inexplicably got burned into real customer hardware.

A firmware upgrade fixed this. I thought I did it from a Linux machine command line (which would usually work on a Mac), but maybe not.